# Controllers are not detected in the Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and the application starts successfully.

But I don't know why I am getting 404 error when hitting `http://localhost:8080/home`.

[image]

The controller code :

```
package com.badar.muneer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

I have tried to put all the controllers in same package as Spring Boot application class and also in it's subpackage but nothing works out.

Can somebody tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Put `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`. It will work.

**Note:** `@RestController` is a meta-annotation which includes both `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller`

Modify to this:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer too！I recommend this answer, because now most of the front and back ends are separated, and there is no need to write web pages in the spring project

Comment: @AnishB. Thanks its working now. I tried a lot this type of solution before, putting `@ResponseBody`, `@RestController` and other solutions on stack overflow, but what worked for me was changing spring boot version from 3.0.3 to 3.0.2 in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ResponseBody` to your method `sayHello`

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public @ResponseBody String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

without `@ResponseBody`,when use  `@Controller`, spring will find view page from the source dir.

In fact, @Anish B.'s answer is also the correct answer

The `@RestController` is

```
package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Controller.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `@ResponseBody` annotation to mentioned method. otherwise 'Hello World' is considered as page (jsp) to render.

Also for debugging try adding a sysout's in `sayHello()`, this is help to pin point the exact failure. If sysout gets printed and still you see 404 , it is most likely a view issue.